# Sharepoint 2013 Javascript ClientPeoplePicker default value text

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint

I'm writing a form in sharepoint 2013 that captures the form via javascript and submits. Everything works, for the most part. However with ClientPeoplePicker, when I get the value, it returns the "Enter a name or email" line as well as my value. Easy enough to parse out, but still annoying as I feel like it shouldn't work that way.

Sadly I am not getting the value in the way that everyone else online is, because "ClientPeoplePicker" never shows up in my rendered code id. I have no idea why. So I am forced to get it by title only.

```js
function formatUserArrayForSharePoint(selector) {
  var users = [];
  $.each(selector, function (i, v) {
    var html = $.parseHTML(v.outerHTML);
    var username = '';
    if ($(html[0]).text().indexOf('Enter a name') !== -1)
      username = $(html[0]).text(0.substring(32, $(html[0]).text().length - 1);
    else username = $(html[0]).text();
    users.push(SP.FieldUserValue.fromUser(username));
  });
  return users;
}

//fill the variable to add to list
field1 = formatUserArrayForSharePoint($("div[title='ascpp']));
oListItem.set_item('field1', field1);
//etc
```

```html
<SharePoint:ClientPeoplePicker
  AllowMultipleEntities="false"
  runat="server" Title="ascpp"
  ID="field1" AllowEmailAddresses="True" />
```

Like I said before, when my code renders, there is no format of the id like other examples are.

Example of what others use:

```html
var pickerDiv = $("[id$='ClientPeoplePicker'][title='" + dispTitle + "']");
```

Example of my rendered code (not entire thing):

```html
<div id="ct100_PlaceHolderMain_field1_TopSpan" class="sp-peoplepicker-topLevel" title="ascpp" spclientpeoplepicker="true">
  <!-- other stuff that is too much to type -->
</div>
```

Comment: This is a js function I used a while back, give it a try `function SetPeoplePickerValue(fieldName, userAccountName) {
    var peoplePickerDiv = jQuery("[spclientpeoplepicker='true'][title='" + fieldName + "']");
    var peoplePickerEditor = peoplePickerDiv.find("[title='" + fieldName + "']");
    var spPeoplePicker = SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict[peoplePickerDiv[0].id];
    peoplePickerEditor.val(userAccountName);
    spPeoplePicker.AddUnresolvedUserFromEditor(true);
};`

Answer (score 0):

It appears the answer is to just strip the unneeded characters off.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the picker id for SharePoint Client People Picker change event. I have got the same using `OnUserResolvedClientScript` as below. Here to get the picker div I have followed the approach of getting it via the people picker text box `id` and the `title name` which you can get the by inspecting the element. put the below code in  `$(document).ready` function. Happy Coding

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc('clientpeoplepicker.js', 'SPClientPeoplePicker', function() {
var pickerDiv = $("[id^='Employee_x0020_Name'][title='Employee Name']");
var picker = SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict[pickerDiv[0].id];
 picker.OnUserResolvedClientScript = function(peoplePickerId, selectedUsersInfo) {
  //It will get the desired display name of the people from picker div, similarly any other property can be accessed via selectedUsersInfo
    var empname = selectedUsersInfo[0].DisplayText;
     console.log(empname);
   }
});
```